# How to create view from one table based on contents of another table

Tags: sql

case...tableA contains a full list of training courses, date and time etc... tableB contains a list of training course names which is a subset of tableA that may change from time to time.

How can I create a view to extract data from tableA to exclude (or include) those records where the couse names appear in tableB?

Comment: Please tag RDBMS that you use.

Comment: `WHERE` section with subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery in the where statement, would be a little easier if I knew the column names but essentially it would look something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE COURSENAME NOT IN (SELECT COURSENAME FROM TABLEB)
```